# Export variable from C++ static library

Tags: c++, export

I have a static library written in C++ and I have a structure describing data format, i.e.

```
struct Format{
    long fmtId;
    long dataChunkSize;
    long headerSize;

    Format(long, long, long);

    bool operator==(Format const & other) const;
};
```

Some of data formats are widely used, like `{fmtId=0, dataChunkSize=128, headerSize=0}` and `{fmtId=0, dataChunkSize=256, headerSize=0}`
Some data structure classes receive format in constructor. I'd like to have some sort of shortcuts for those widely used formats, like a couple of global `Format` members `gFmt128, gFmt256` that I can pass by reference. I instantiate them in a .cpp file like

`Format gFmt128(0, 128, 0);`

and in .h there is

`extern Format gFmt128;`

also, I declare `Format const & Format::Fmt128(){return gFmt128;}` and try to use it in the main module.

But if I try and do it in the main module that uses the lib, the linker complains about unresolved external `gFmt128`.

How can I make my library 'export' those global vars, so I can use them from other modules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use the static keyword on global declarations. [Here is an article explain the visibility of variables with/without static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd.aspx). The static gives globals internal linkage, that is, only visible in the translation unit they are declared in.

Answer (score 2):

Are they defined in .cpp file as well? Roughly, it should look like:

```
struct Format
{
    [...]
    static Format gFmt128;
};
// Format.cpp
Format Format::gFmt128 = { 0, 128, 0 }
```

Comment: This seems the correct way for a C++ object. Here the static makes the struct member gFmt128 a class variable rather than a global variable with internal linkage.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your Format objects as **extern** not **static**